Why does this client side `fetch` trigger a CWE-918: Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF)?
I'm trying to resolve a critical Server-side request forgery (SSRF) (see also warning as a result of a Semgrep SAST scanning and I'm not sure what else to do.
In the following snippet I've replaced url with a hard coded absolute URL and I've created url with URL. Nothing has worked so far.
This code does not run on the server and is taken from react-relay.
 const resp = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept:
        "application/graphql-response+json; charset=utf-8, application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: request.text,
      variables,
    }),
  });

